# My Ubuntu box restarted without warning, what log files do I need to examine?

Tags: 20.04, logs

My Ubuntu box restarted without warning, what log files do I need to examine? Specifically,, (1) which log files will tell me what forced a sudden restart? And (2) where do I find them?

**Update:** Following [waltinator's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1354881/145472) I ran `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` and spotted:

```
 smartd[1310]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 108 to 109
```

I suspect I have a thermal problem.

Also did this:

```
  [  me  ]:/var/log$ ls -al /var/crash
  total 4936
  drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 Jul 30 07:40 .
  drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root        4096 Jun  5  2017 ..
  -rw-r-----  1 [  me  ] whoopsie 4537678 Jul 24 12:50 _usr_bin_simple-scan.1000.crash
  -rw-r--r--  1 [  me  ] whoopsie       0 Jul 24 10:34 _usr_bin_simple-scan.1000.upload
  -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Jul 24 10:34 _usr_bin_simple-scan.1000.uploaded
  -rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie  498295 Jul 24 10:57 _usr_sbin_ippusbxd.0.crash
  -rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie       0 Jul 24 10:53 _usr_sbin_ippusbxd.0.upload
  -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Jul 24 10:53 _usr_sbin_ippusbxd.0.uploaded
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Check `ls -al /var/crash` for crash logs... if there's output, edit that into your question. Next do `more /var/log/syslog` and look around the time when the restart occurred, and see what happened just before that. Do you have any temperature monitoring utilities installed? What version Ubuntu?

Comment: Install gnome-extension `freon` or `vitals` to get a better idea about your temps.

Comment: See if https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ippusbxd/+bug/1877095 applies to your situation.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I had a freeze up just today and my thermals looked okay (I was displaying the graphics card at the time on the menu bar). It seems to always happen while viewing YouTube videos on Chrome but that could be a coincidence.

Comment: Does it occur when you print or scan? Try using Firefox to view YouTube videos and see if you have the same problem. Report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: I think you might be right about a thermal issue.