# I need some help understanding the output of journalctl as it relates to system crashing/freezing

Tags: 20.04, kernel, crash, log, ufw

I've been getting a lot of freeze-ups and the odd sudden reboot recently. Most often it happens while I am streaming media. The freeze-up infinitely loops that last (approximately) 1 second of audio. I thought I had found and solved it several times but have been wrong every time.

I tried running memtest during the bootup but it freezes at 15%, 30% or 40% depending on the settings I chose. I understand this can and does happen with some BIOS and boards.

I ran SMART and saw a few features marked pre-fail. (I plan to buy a newer drive and clone the contents of the old one onto its replacement when I can afford to).

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1354881/145472) to [my question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1354877/145472), I ran `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`.

I understand from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/184290/145472) that UFW BLOCK means a connection was blocked. It comes up a lot in the tail end of the output (I redirected the output to a text file).

On these local IP addresses, 254 is my router and 103 is my PC

```
Aug 27 17:53:44 Hope systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Aug 27 17:53:44 Hope dbus-daemon[997]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug 27 17:53:44 Hope systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Aug 27 17:53:44 Hope hud-service[3437]: void DBusMenuImporter::slotGetLayoutFinished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*): "No such interface “com.canonical.dbusmenu” on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/window/65013137"
Aug 27 17:53:49 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=302 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51143 DPT=42922 LEN=282 
Aug 27 17:54:09 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=302 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51143 DPT=42922 LEN=282 
Aug 27 17:54:14 Hope systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Aug 27 17:54:28 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62508 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:54:49 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62514 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:55:08 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 17:55:28 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 17:55:49 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=302 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51143 DPT=42922 LEN=282 
Aug 27 17:56:09 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 17:56:29 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 17:56:48 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62554 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:57:09 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=302 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51143 DPT=42922 LEN=282 
Aug 27 17:57:28 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 17:57:49 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62573 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:58:08 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62579 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:58:29 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62589 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:58:48 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62595 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:59:08 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 17:59:28 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62606 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 17:59:48 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62613 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:00:08 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62619 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:00:35 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:30:cd:a7:a8:fd:fc:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.205 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=267 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=92 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=247 
Aug 27 18:00:48 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62635 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:01:08 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62641 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:01:28 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62647 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:01:48 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 18:02:08 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 18:02:29 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62669 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:02:49 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395 
Aug 27 18:03:09 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:94:9a:a9:a4:76:8c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.237 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=467 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=62681 PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=447 
Aug 27 18:03:28 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:67:9f:6e:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=415 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=42922 LEN=395
```

Am I looking at the right part of the file?

Is there a crash reason clue here?

Where else might I look?

#### free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3.5Gi       7.9Gi       377Mi       4.3Gi        11Gi
Swap:          28Gi          0B        28Gi
```

#### sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60

#### swapon -s

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5               partition   29668348    0   -2
```

#### sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 080015
       date: 03/26/2010
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory:0
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-08-02 16:47+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 8bd362bf86c4b35e805f897f03c203e3576a7006) Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: CMV4GX3M1A1333C9
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-08-02 16:47+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 8bd362bf86c4b35e805f897f03c203e3576a7006) Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: CMV4GX3M1A1333C9
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-08-02 16:47+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 8bd362bf86c4b35e805f897f03c203e3576a7006) Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: CMV4GX3M1A1333C9
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-08-02 16:47+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 8bd362bf86c4b35e805f897f03c203e3576a7006) Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: CMV4GX3M1A1333C9
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM3
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
  *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: MCP61 Memory Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
       capabilities: ht bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: MCP61 Memory Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 1.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
       version: a2
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
       configuration: latency=0
```

**Further Update**: So, I opened up my PC and used Memtest68+ 5.01 from the GRUB menu on each stick of RAM. They all passed. It took a few hours. I'm in no hurry to do that again.

Update top the further update: I also took a look at the UFW BLOCK records and explicitly allowed the more common broadcasts on my network. So those UDP errors are unlikely to be a continuing issue.

**Further further update**: I sorted out most of those UDP blocks and the last run ended like this:

```
Sep 03 21:34:42 Hope systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Sep 03 21:34:42 Hope systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Sep 03 21:34:42 Hope anacron[19507]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-09-03
Sep 03 21:34:42 Hope anacron[19507]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Sep 03 21:35:56 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 03 21:38:01 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 03 21:39:01 Hope CRON[19572]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 03 21:39:01 Hope CRON[19571]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 03 21:39:01 Hope CRON[19573]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Sep 03 21:39:01 Hope CRON[19571]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 03 21:39:01 Hope CRON[19574]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)
Sep 03 21:39:01 Hope CRON[19572]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 03 21:39:02 Hope systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Sep 03 21:39:02 Hope sessionclean[19644]: /usr/lib/php/sessionclean: 35: php7.0: not found
Sep 03 21:39:02 Hope systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Sep 03 21:39:02 Hope systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Sep 03 21:40:06 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 03 21:42:11 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2
```

> **Update #1:**
>
> `memtest` freezes when run. Suspect bad RAM, or RAM that needs re-seating in its socket. RAM is in slots DIMM0-3. Remove DIMMs1-3 and retest `memtest`. If `memtest` runs without error, add back one DIMM into slot DIMM1 and retest, etc.

### Big ol' update (as requested)

#### free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3.3Gi       5.0Gi       144Mi       7.4Gi        11Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

#### Request grep

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=01eaad91-0858-4b01-8cad-76671cf8682d none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

#### swapon

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        4194300 0   -2
```

#### HDD Screenshots

[image]

[image]

#### An updated `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`.

I've solved some of the UDP block reports by allowing them due to being harmless home network broadcasts.

```
Sep 05 17:25:06 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 05 17:27:11 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 05 17:29:16 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 05 17:30:01 Hope CRON[31486]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 05 17:30:01 Hope CRON[31487]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Sep 05 17:30:01 Hope CRON[31486]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 05 17:31:21 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Sep 05 17:32:33 Hope systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Sep 05 17:32:33 Hope anacron[31544]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-09-05
Sep 05 17:32:33 Hope anacron[31544]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Sep 05 17:32:33 Hope systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Sep 05 17:33:01 Hope smartd[1067]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 107 to 108
Sep 05 17:33:01 Hope smartd[1067]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 153 to 157
Sep 05 17:33:02 Hope smartd[1067]: Device: /dev/sdc [SAT], 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Sep 05 17:33:26 Hope kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:44:fe:3b:c4:a4:0d:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2
```

I thought HDD is getting too hot. [Turns out those are index values](https://serverfault.com/questions/693163/is-smartd-really-reporting-this-drive-is-too-hot).

Comment: Sounds like three separate issues. The freezing... edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. The UFW BLOCK has to do with UPnP. Do you have something like a media server running? Memory test freezes are almost always an indication of bad RAM. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Edited as directed. The blocked inbound connections seem to be my printer and/or router UDP broadcasts.

Comment: Turn off UPnP in your router. It's a security risk. What are the other IP addresses in your report? Run `memtest`. Your swap partition is way too big. What version Ubuntu? Report back.

Comment: I'm running 20.14

Comment: Do you mean 20.04? Did you run `memtest`?

Comment: I did mean to type 20.04. I failed to run memtest or, rather, failed to get my motherboard to boot from a USB stick.

Comment: How did you make the USB flash key? Did you make it on this computer, or a different computer? Do you see anything on the screen when you try and boot to `memtest`? Have you overclocked your CPU or RAM?

Comment: No overclocking. Had trouble making the USB on my machine so made it on a Windows box.

Comment: What program did you try on Ubuntu? `Startup Disk Creator`? What program did you use on Windows? `Rufus`?

Comment: dd with Linux whatever came with memtest with windows.

Comment: Try using `Startup Disk Creator` under Ubuntu, on the machine that you wish to test.

Comment: Sadly the startup still stalls early on same as always.

Comment: Please clarify... startup stalls on normal Ubuntu boot... or startup of the `memtest` USB? Did you rebuild the USB using `Startup Disk Creator`? Is this a desktop computer?

Comment: Memtest. Every which way I try it, Memtest stalls after the hardware monitor page which is when GRUB would kick in on a normal boot. I activated the POST memory check and that reports OK.

Comment: Is this a desktop computer? Does the hardware monitor page normally come up, or only when it detects a problem? Your RAM is in slots DIMM0-3. Carefully remove the DIMMS1-3, leaving only DIMM0. Then retry `memtest`. If it runs, add back DIMM1 and retry `memtest`. Report back.

Comment: Yes, it is a desktop. I will report back when I have faffed with the RAM and have something to report.

Comment: I ran Memtest86+ 5.01 on each stick of RAM. All passed.

Answer (score 1):

**memtest**

You may have a hardware problem.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**swap**

Unless you hibernate, your swap partition is way too big. We'll replace it with a 4G /swapfile.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

**Note**: Remove other existing swap lines. Use `gparted` to delete /dev/sda5.

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

`memtest` freezes when run. Suspect bad RAM, or RAM that needs re-seating in its socket. RAM is in slots DIMM0-3. Remove DIMMs1-3 and retest `memtest`. If `memtest` runs without error, add back one DIMM into slot DIMM1 and retest, etc.

**Update #2:**

It looks like your sdc drive has one or more bad blocks. Let's map it out...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #3:**

Since deleting /dev/sda5, you're left with a 28G unallocated hole on your HDD. You can add that space to /dev/sda1.

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **Delete** /dev/sda2 extended partition
- **Resize** the right side of /dev/sda1 all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: `sudo rm -i /swapfile` responds with `rm: cannot remove '/swapfile': No such file or directory`

Comment: All memory tested (see update). All memory passed.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Yes, the `rm` command is expected to not find that file. That file would only be there if previously created. Continue on with the rest of the procedure. Good news on `memtest`. With all memory reinstalled, did you run `memtest` again? Does it freeze now? It may have been a DIMM that needed re-seating.

Comment: Got as far as reading the fstab when I had a freeze up. Back to old swap size. The second time's the charm, I hope.

Comment: All done. I have a block of unallocated space on my primary HDD but that's not a big deal.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `swapon -s` and I'll check it for you. Show me a screenshot of `gparted` and maybe it'll be simple use that unallocated space on your HDD. Also start `Disks`, click on the 3-dot icon, select SMART Data & Tests, get to the data window, resize it to show all data, take a screenshot, and I'll also take a look.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Status please...

Comment: Added just now.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt The swap looks good. Please see Update #2 and Update #3 in my answer.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Status please...

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Status please...

Comment: I'm going to make a bootable disk. Sorry for the delay - I was AFK for a number of days.